# REST request to update GMAIL signature with Domain validation

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I've created the below code with some help to access any user's signature on my domain in order to standardize the signature across users. Currently, When I specify method 'PATCH' in the URLFetch parameters, All I get is the sendAs resource of the email I sent, including the old signature. If I specify the PUT method, it removes the signature, but will not set the signature I specified onto the account. Could someone help me see what I am doing wrong?

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION SET SIGNATURE////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Authorizes and makes a request to the GMail API.
 */
function setSignature(user)
{
  var user = 'me@mydomain.com';
  var newSig = '<b>This is my new Signature!</b>';
  var service = getService(user);
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+user+'/settings/sendAs/'+user;
      
      var payload =
      {
        "sendAsEmail" : user,
        "displayName" : AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName,
        "type" : "patch",
        "replyToAddress" : user,
        "signature": newSig
      };
  
  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "PUT",
        "payload" : payload,   
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "contentType": "ctAPPLICATION_JSON",
        "headers": {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}
      };
        
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION VIEW SIGNATURE////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function viewSignature(user) { var user = USER_EMAIL;
  var service = getService(user);
    Logger.log(service.hasAccess());
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+user+'/settings/sendAs';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION RESET//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
 */
function reset() {
  var service = getService();
  service.reset();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION GET SERVICE////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService(user) {
  return OAuth2.createService('Gmail:' + user)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
      // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
      // delegation:
      // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
      .setSubject(user)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing');
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTION CLEAR SIGNATURE////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function clearService(){
  OAuth2.createService('drive')
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
 .reset();
}
```

NOTE: OAuth2 Credentials are stored in Constant variables in a separate file, but I have verified that the credentials return valid data.

Thanks,

Comment: Interestingly, patch function in advanced services google scripts works with the above-mentioned payload. I know you may not be able to use the advanced services, this is just FYI. Hope some else can figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apps works, problem is contentType.

Try:

```
var formData = {'sendAsEmail':user,'type':'patch','signature': newSig}
    var options =
      {
        'method'  : 'put',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()},
        'payload': JSON.stringify(formData)
      };
```